Laravel Database Queue Multiple Workers Not Working On Job Concurrently
Workers Not Running In Parallel Laravel 5.5 Database Connection Type
I have a Laravel project running version 5.5, with the queue system set up using the database connection type.
The queue is functioning as expected, where each dispatched job is picked up by the assigned worker, processed, and removed from the job table upon completion.
However, I've encountered a backlog of jobs because the worker is unable to clear jobs faster than they are being created. It clears roughly 60 jobs per minute.
To resolve this, I increased the number of workers from 1 to 3, but the number of jobs being cleared remains the same (60 jobs per minute).
After adding some logging to the jobs being processed, I discovered that whenever Worker A is processing a job, Worker B remains idle, and vice versa. It appears that only one worker is active at a time, and they are not processing jobs in parallel.
What could be causing this, and how can I ensure that multiple workers process jobs concurrently in Laravel with a database queue?
What is the issue?
Queue Set Up Code
QUEUE_DRIVER = database

Job Dispatching Code
dispatch(new \App\Jobs\ProcessRobotCameraStreamJob($mqttTopic, $messageJsonFormat));

Supervisor
[program:teleops_queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:work --tries=5 --timeout=300 --queue=teleops_robot_position
directory=/var/www/html
logfile_maxbytes=0
logfile_backups=0
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
numprocs=3
autorestart=true
startretries=86400

Sudo supervisorctl status
teleops_queue:teleops_queue_00             RUNNING   pid 1, uptime 2:29:03
teleops_queue:teleops_queue_01             RUNNING   pid 2, uptime 2:29:03
teleops_queue:teleops_queue_02             RUNNING   pid 3, uptime 2:29:03


The issue might be due to database lock contention preventing multiple workers from processing jobs concurrently. Consider switching to a more concurrent queue driver like Redis or SQS for better performance with multiple workers.

Does connection database not work?

Its not a database connection issue.
